# Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink, toplink

I have a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Indexes(value={
        @Index(name="idx_produto", columnNames={"codigoInterno"}),
        @Index(name="idx_produto_ean_com",columnNames={"eanComercial"}),
        @Index(name="idx_prod_unicidade",columnNames={"codigoInterno","empresa_id"})
})
@Customizer(ProdutoCustomizer.class)
@AggressiveCache
public class Produto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4801725521366642420L;


    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false, length=14)
    @NotEmpty(message="É obrigatório um código interno")
    @Length(max=14, message="O código interno não pode ultrapassar 14 digitos")
    private String codigoInterno;

    @Embedded
    private Combustivel combustivel = new Combustivel();
```

when I try to "delete" this entity, I got this error:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-6002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners. 
Descriptor: [RelationalDescriptor(br.com.germantech.ecf.dominio.modelo.produto.Combustivel --> [])]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(br.com.germantech.ecf.dominio.modelo.produto.Combustivel@1a7cbdd)
```

Actually, I do not remove the entity from database. as seen, I have and customizer which just set the product as inactive, like this

```
public class ProdutoCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) {
        descriptor.getQueryManager().setDeleteSQLString("update Produto set ativo = false where id = #ID");
    }
```

so, what am I missing here? the `Combustivel` **MUST** be embedded, I can't change that

**Edit** 
The stacktrace

```
[EL Warning]: 2013-03-21 10:59:34.659--UnitOfWork(12940738)--Thread(Thread[main,6,main])--Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.1.v20121003-ad44345): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Aggregated objects cannot be written/deleted/queried independently from their owners. 
Descriptor: [RelationalDescriptor(br.com.germantech.ecf.dominio.modelo.produto.Combustivel --> [])]
Query: DeleteObjectQuery(br.com.germantech.ecf.dominio.modelo.produto.Combustivel@d4ca28)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.aggregateObjectCannotBeDeletedOrWritten(QueryException.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.prepare(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.prepare(DeleteObjectQuery.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DeleteObjectQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(DeleteObjectQuery.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2875)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1535)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.deleteAllObjects(CommitManager.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitToDatabase(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1509)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.commitRootUnitOfWork(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at br.com.germantech.ecf.aplicacao.interceptors.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:72)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:52)
    at br.com.germantech.ecf.infraestrutura.persistencia.repositorios.ProdutoRepositoryImpl$$EnhancerByGuice$$d68cdfa4.delete(<generated>)
    at br.com.germantech.ecf.infraestrutura.persistencia.repositorios.ProdutoRepositoryImpl.delete(ProdutoRepositoryImpl.java:1)
    at br.com.germantech.ecf.aplicacao.services.ProdutoService.delete(ProdutoService.java:66)
    at br.com.germantech.ecf.telas.editors.ProdutoEditor.excluirRegistro(ProdutoEditor.java:231)
    at br.com.germantech.ecf.telas.editors.GermantechEditor$2.widgetSelected(GermantechEditor.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at br.com.germantech.ecf.aplicacao.internal.Application.start(Application.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Comment: Please include the exception stack trace, ensure you do not call remove on the Embedded object.

Comment: edited and included. I do not call remove on the Embedded object

Comment: anything? can you reproduce this, @James?

Comment: it looks like remove was called on it,  how is Combustivel mapped?  what does @AggressiveCache do?  what if you remove your customizer?  Try setting logging to finest to see what is occurring.

Comment: this is Combustivel: https://gist.github.com/luizkowalski/5238631 I have 100% sure that we do not call delete on Combustivel, thats why I think this is weird. @AggresiveCache just redirect find* queries, based on this article: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/zarar/archive/2010/06/01/integrating-eclipsellink-ehcache-cache-readall-and-native-queries

Comment: this is the output when the log is set to FINEST https://gist.github.com/luizkowalski/5238690

Comment: I removed the relation from Combustivel to Produto, and now I can deactivated the Produto with the query customizer...guess that embedded entities should not contain @ManyToOne or similars

Comment: Note that for the @AggressiveCache EHCache redirector, EclipseLink does support this, see, http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Caching/Query_Cache